# Facebook php API and app_data parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am building an application for Facebook that needs to be able to retrieve some custom parameters. I read that app_data is my solution and that I can easily retrieve the data I need by putting them there.

Now, I have made a custom page tab dialog that work great - really.

```
$response = $facebook->api("/".$pageWhereToInstallApp."/tabs","POST",array ('app_id' => $appID,'access_token'=>$accessToken));
```

As far as I've understood it the app_data parameter needs to be passed when the page tab is created. But, I can't find anywhere how I specify this parameter in the above code.

Any help is much appriciated.
Thank you.

/Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I've understood it the app_data parameter needs to be passed when the page tab is created.

That’s wrong (and would not make much sense, because that way it would be a rather static parameter).

You have to pass it when you *link* to your page tab app from somewhere external:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_0123456789?app_data=foo
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to clarify that for me :)